# Form ajax call to PHP page not working

Tags: jquery, form-submit

All of the other questions similar to this are pretty specific to the asker's particular situation so I thought I'd ask mine.

I'm just trying to send a form to it's action page using ajax but for some reason the page still refreshes when the form is submitted. Any ideas why?

Form:

```
  <form name='comment_form' id='comment_form' action='leave_comments.php' onSubmit='return validateForm()'>              
  <input type='text' name='user_comment' class='user_comment' placeholder='Leave a comment...'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_title' value='$title'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name'  value='$image_name'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_user' value='$posted_by'>          
  <input type='submit' class='leave_comment button' name='leave_comment button' value='Comment'>
  </form>
```

The JS validation:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var o=document.forms["leave_comments_form"]["user_comment"].value;
    if (o==null || o=="")
    {
        alert("Error 2591 : Whoops, looks like you forgot to leave a comment!");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

The JS ajax:

```
<script>
$("#comment_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (validateForm()) {
        var form = jQuery("#comment_form");   
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function() {}
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm just trying to get the form to submit without a page refresh.

Comment: **DEVELOPERS CONSOLE**

Comment: Why do you use jQuery in the submit function, but not the valide function?

Comment: To what does `document.forms["leave_comments_form"]` refer? It doesn't seem to exist in your HTML.

Comment: @showdev typo error.fixed it

Comment: You shouldn't call `validateForm()` from both the `onsubmit` attribute and also in the jQuery handler. That will call it twice.

Comment: ^thanks, error corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`validateForm()` needs to return `true` when the validation is successful:

```
function validateForm() {
    var o=document.forms["leave_comments_form"]["user_comment"].value;
    if (o==null || o=="")
    {
        alert("Error 2591 : Whoops, looks like you forgot to leave a comment!");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This isn't needed for the `onsubmit` attribute, but it is needed when you write `if (validateForm())`, because `undefined` is falsy.

Comment: implemented suggested changes.still get the page refresh unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your submit button. Move it outside of the `<form>` tags, or use a button instead.

```
<form name='comment_form' id='comment_form' action='leave_comments.php' onSubmit='return validateForm()'>              
  <input type='text' name='user_comment' class='user_comment' placeholder='Leave a comment...'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_title' value='$title'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name'  value='$image_name'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>
  <input type='hidden' name='hidden_user' value='$posted_by'>          
  </form>
<input type='submit' class='leave_comment button' name='leave_comment button' value='Comment'>
```